# Creating a Standard "Day" View for Calendar, not showing Recurring Events or Events that span over several days

Tags: list-view, calendar, recurring-events

I'm trying to create a standard view for my calendar, to show Today items only. I'm successful with the filtering for this, however I cannot figure out how to get it to show Recurring events or events that started or end on days other than today. I've tried the Standard View with Expanded Recurring Events, however there are no Start time & End time filtering options, so I'm not sure how to achieve this "Today" view. Anyone able to help??

Comment: Take a look at spservices plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works nicely for me:

1. In SharePoint, create a new list view starting from an existing Current Events view or using the Standard View, with Expanded Recurring Events.
2. Go to Site Actions and select Edit Page.
3. Edit your new list view web part and select Current Events as the view.
4. Stop editing the page.
5. Apply additional filters by modifying the view (skip this step if you aren’t using any other filters).
6. Create at least 1 calendar event. (SharePoint Designer must have at least 1 row of data to make fields available)
7. Open SharePoint Designer and open the new view you created in Step 1.
8. Right-Click on the top row of the view and Select>Row.
9. Under Conditional Formatting, select “Apply Formatting…”
10. Under the Field Name, scroll to the bottom of the drop-down list and select “More Fields…”.
11. Check the box named “Show data values”
12. Scroll down and select the Start Time field (@EventDate).
13. Leave the Comparison field set to “Equals”
14. Leave the Value field set to [Current Date].
15. Click on Set Style to set a background or font color.
16. Right-Click on the top row of the view and Select>Row again.
17. Under Conditional Formatting, select “Hide Content…”
18. Under the Field Name, scroll to the bottom of the drop-down list and select “More Fields…”.
19. Check the box named “Show data values”
20. Scroll down and select the Start Time field (@EventDate).
21. Change the Comparison field set to “Not Equals”
22. Leave the Value field set to [Current Date].
23. Save and Refresh SharePoint Designer.

Note-The color formatting in steps 8-14 can be removed if no color formatting is preferred. For some reason, the Conditional Formatting-Hide Content wouldn’t work unless apply formatting was first used.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to make a Today List with reccurance events tat work is.

1. Create a Standard view with expanded recurring Events
2. Open the new view with Sharepoint Designer and in the view section search for "now" and replace it with "Today"

Attention: if you make some changes in the view in Sharepoint.... The changes where cancelled so it is better first make oll settings for the view and at the end make the change in Sharepoint Designer.